# How to do a scaffold over a ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, postgresql, asp.net-core, scaffolding

I have a postgres database on a remote computer that I need to use

To log on to that computer I do the usual,

```
ssh <myuser>@<subdomain.domain.com> -p <custom port>
```

Once logged in, I must again

```
ssh <someServerName>
```

Then I can do

```
psql -U postgres -W
```

and get into the database

So in short, I need to do `ssh something` twice

Is it possible to connect to this database **using entity framework core**?

Bonus question: Would this be called a ssh tunnel?

**Solution**

It´s called Port Fowarding

```
using (var client = new SshClient("<public ip>", <port>, "<myuser>", "<mypassword>"))
{
    client.Connect();

    var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 5432, "10.0.0.5", 5432);
    client.AddForwardedPort(port);

    port.Start();

    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=<secret>;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=<secret>;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    port.Stop();
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to run psql command from your local host, you can do :

```
ssh -t <myuser>@<subdomain.domain.com> -p <custom port> ssh -t <someServerName> psql -U postgres -W
```

To do the port forwarding (SSH tunneling), you can do in one terminal :

```
ssh -L 5432:someServerName:5432 <myuser>@<subdomain.domain.com> -p <custom port>
```

`-L 5432:someServerName:5432` means now the port 5432 on localhost is forwarded to someServerName:5432 (port used by postgres)

Comment: so sorry I forgot to add that I need to connect using net core entity framework

Comment: Thanks buddy you saved me!